# create responsive div for banner

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

how to create responsive div like img-responsive class in bootstrap but for a div 
that when window size change, height of div element change related to its width..

like this website slider "http://sabanet.ir"
when you change window size the slider keep the ratio of height to width...

am i should use javascript to do it or i can do it with css or bootstrap?

```
    <div class="responsive-banner">
        <!-- height/width === k -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you know about bootstrap grid system? Like .row and .col ?

Comment: Using a single set of .col-md-* grid classes, you can create a basic grid system that starts out stacked on mobile devices and tablet devices (the extra small to small range) before becoming horizontal on desktop (medium) devices. Place grid columns in any .row.

Comment: grid systems use for width not height i need something that change the height

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by `@media` queries if you're not looking to support legacy IE.

Define the minimum and maximum width / height of the viewport and assign the height property based on break points.

Example would be:

```
@media only screen
and (min-width: 320px) /* Define any min width that you deem appropriate */
and (max-width: 480px){ /* Define any max width that you deem appropriate */
.responsive-banner{
     height:200px /* Enter any value that you deem appropriate */
}
}
```

You can use multiple of the above queries to define different break points or ranges.

Comment: isn't there any class in bootstrap? like img-responsive?

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use Bootstrap Grid System.

eg:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    This is text 1
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    This is text 2
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    This is text 3 
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    This is text 4
    </div>
  </div>
```

include bootstrap CSS (you can download and give local path or you can give **cdn** path ,too).

Now what i have done is.

I have taken one bootstrap **row** , and divided it into 4 same width and height columns. so whatever you write in respective column , will be surrounded by default width of column.

and in that **column class div** , when you put your custom div , it will be responsive according to the size of the browser window.

Comment: my question is something else

Answer (score 0):

after searching and thinking i guess that some ways to do it

## Using css units :

we can use css units for relatively size 

em : Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

ex :    Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used) 

ch :    Relative to width of the "0" (zero)

rem: Relative to font-size of the root element

vw :    Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport*

we can use vw  unit to set the height of the div element like below

```
.responsive-banner {
    height: 30vw;
}
```

## Using jquery :

first we set favorite ratio to a variable and after it change the height of element by its width

```
var ratio = 700/1920;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.responsive-banner').height(ratio * $('.responsive-banner').width());
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.responsive-banner').height(ratio * $('.responsive-banner').width());
})
```